# process catch SIGINT signal using sigint_handler

Tags: c, linux, shell

I encountered this problem when doing shell lab from the book CSAPP, the lab ask you to implement your own version of shell with some specification,one of them is

> Typing ctrl-c (ctrl-z) should cause a SIGINT (SIGTSTP) signal to be
>   sent to the current foreground job, as well as any descendents of that
>   job (e.g., any child processes that it forked). If there is no
>   foreground job, then the signal should have no effect.

so you should complete one of the given functions called sigint_handler which supposed to catch SIGINT signal and send it along to the foreground job. below is a piece of code I find online(the code passed the correctness check)

```
void sigint_handler(int sig) 
{
    int olderrno = errno;
    pid_t pid = fgpid(jobs);
    if (pid != 0)
        kill(-pid, sig);
    errno = olderrno;
    return;
}
```

what I don't understand is if SIGINT is sent using kill,then the descendents of foreground job will also use this   handler to catch SIGINT signal right? so it's  kind of a recursive call to me.so how does this actually work? thanks for helping me.

handler is installed in the main function

```
signal(SIGINT,  sigint_handler);   /* ctrl-c */
```

and fgpid return PID of current foreground job, 0 if no such job

Comment: We don't see all the code. Where is the handler installed? How is it installed? What does `fgpid` return? What if `fgpid` returns `pid = 0` in descendant jobs? Wouldn't that count as the stop condition?

Comment: I updated question description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a child process calls `execve()`, the child's (usually short-lived) initial address space is freed/released and replaced with space for the specified executable image; now the child no longer has a copy or access to the parent's data or text, like signal handlers.

Now consider a process-group associated with the control-terminal (tty).  When a user types a CTRL-C (or CTRL-\ or CTRL-Z), the tty driver posts a signal to 1+ processes as members of the associated process-group.  The result of delivering a signal would be the system default action unless a process established a different signal disposition (`signal()`, `sigaction()`, or related).

The posted code excerpt indicates a relayed event: user types a CTRL-C, tty driver posts a SIGINT to the shell, shell's handler looks for a foreground job, calls `kill()` with a negative `pid` to post a signal to members of that process-group.

For related info see these man pages:

```
man setpgrp
man tty_ioctl  (symbols: TIOCSCTTY, TIOCGPGRP, TIOCSPGRP)

alternates:
man tcgetpgrp tcsetpgrp
```

Comment: thanks，so if I just use fork to ceate a child process without execve the child process will use the same sigint_handler right?